# GNU make loop variable strange behavior

Tags: shell, for-loop, makefile, gnu

In my Makefile I am trying to copy a list of files from location1 to location2, then to location2 to location3. I got the following strange behavior:

```
    FILES_LIST=dir1/file1 dir2/file2 dir3/file3 ........

    mytarget:
        for file in $(FILES_LIST) ; do \
            #this works
            cp -vf location1/$$file location2/$(shell $$file##*/) ; \
            #this does not work
            cp -vf location2/$(shell $$(file)##*/) location3/ ; \
        done
```

I am using "$(shell $$(file)##*/)" to strip out "dir1/" part of each item in FILES_LIST.
The first cp works (from location1 to 2), however, the send does not, build log shows "$(shell $$(file)##*/)" is evaluated to empty.

I am using GNU Make 3.81

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `$$(file)`. That's not a variable evaluation. That's a Command Substitution. You meant `$${file}` (well not quite but we'll get to that).

There is also absolutely **no** reason to be using `$(shell)` here at all as you are *already* in a shell context when those lines run.

Not to mention that those `$(shell)` calls aren't doing anything even remotely like what you want (they aren't operating at the right time to do that).

You want this:

```
FILES_LIST=dir1/file1 dir2/file2 dir3/file3 ........

mytarget:
    for file in $(FILES_LIST) ; do \
        #this works
        cp -vf location1/$$file location2/$${file##*/} ; \
        #this does not work
        cp -vf location2/$${file)##*/} location3/ ; \
    done
```

Your `$file` variable is a shell variable not a make one. The call to `$(shell)` does not see it. You are effectively running `$(shell $file##*/)` which runs the `$file##*/` command through the shell. That shell has no `$file` variable so that becomes `##*/` which is a comment and the whole thing returns nothing. (Actually I think the comment may be stripped first but that doesn't change anything.)

Comment: You are right on the spot sir! Thanks for the detailed explanation. "cp -vf location2/$${file##*/} location3/ ; \" worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use $(notdir $file) command.
notdir will strip out the directories and return the filename. For example, $(notdir dir1/file.h) will return file.h

Reference link for more detailed info:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html

Comment: the problem is that the $$file is evaluated to an empty value if I put it in parentheses: here is the log shows : for header in dir1/file1 dir2/file2 dir3/file3; do \
                cp -vf /location2/ /location3 ; \
        done
cp: omitting directory '/location2/'

Comment: since file is defined in your makefile but not in the shell env, $$(file) becomes $(file) in the shell and hence evaluates to NULL. Use a single $ instead of $$, i.e. "cp -vf location2/$(shell $(file)##*/) location3/"

Comment: `$file` is a shell variable not a make variable.

Comment: This answer is heading the wrong direction. This needs to move more towards the shell and not away from it. The `$(notdir)` function doesn't have anything to operate on in make context.

Comment: notdir should be used before the make rule, like this:  
FILES_ONLY=$(notdir $(FILES_LIST)).   Now, FILES_ONLY will contain just the file names and in the make rule, FILES_ONLY should be used in the loop.